# How do I increase an IntegerField in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am making a Todo list web app in Django. I am just learning Django and a very much novice, so any help is greatly appreciated. My problem:

My app will allow users to sign up and they can have a profile of their own. They can create ToDos and delete them as they want. Now, I want to introduce an attribute to all the users called "todos". This is basically an integer value that will keep track of how many todos they have created since they signed up. And every time the user adds a new task, I want this value to increase by 1. I just can't seem to figure out how to implement this.

This is my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile_pics")
    todos = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} Profile"


    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

`views.py`

```
class TodoListView(ListView):
    model = ToDo
    template_name = "ToDo/home.html"
    context_object_name = "todos"
    ordering = ["-date_posted"]


class TodoCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ToDo
    fields = ["title"]
    success_url = reverse_lazy("todo-home")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        user = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)
        user.profile.todos += 1
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In the `form_valid` method, I have tried to increment that value, but this doesn't seem to work. Since I have access to the Admin Panel I can see that when adding a new task, the `todos` count does not increase.

I am looking for a method that can increment this value and I can call it conveniently when required. Additionally, it would be really helpful if someone could show how to get this `todos` count in a template so that I can use this value in the Html. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding user.save() after you increment todos

Comment: Great! It worked just fine. I was really surprised just one line of code solved this problem. Also, can you please help me with how to access this integer in one of my templates? So that I can know how many todos a certain user has completed and thus display appropriate Html content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the save method within the form_valid method

```
class TodoListView(ListView):
    model = ToDo
    template_name = "ToDo/home.html"
    context_object_name = "todos"
    ordering = ["-date_posted"]


class TodoCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ToDo
    fields = ["title"]
    success_url = reverse_lazy("todo-home")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        user = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)
        user.profile.todos += 1
        user.profile.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

If you wish to access these from within the templates you can just use `user.profile.todos` directly. E.G. `{{ user.profile.todos }}` or `{% if user.profile.todos > 1 %}More than one{% endif %}`

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you add `user.save()` it will solve part of your problem

```
user.profile.todos += 1
user.save()
```

But i recommend you to refactor your code adding
`Profile` foreign_key for `ToDo` model, then you can get count with `ToDo.models.filter(profile__user = myuser).count()` and this will give you correct number if you delete `ToDo` object too. In addition it give you opportunity to filter `ToDo` list for specific user.

Also you can make calculated field and call it when you need.

```
class Profile(models.Model)
    ###

    get_todo_count(self):
        return ToDo.models.filter(profile = self).count()
```